# Super long arrays in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, performance

I have two sets A and B. Set A contains unique elements. Set B contains all elements. Each element in the B is a 10 by 10 matrix where all entries are either 1 or 0. I need to scan through set B and everytime i encounter a new matrix i will add it to set A. Therefore set A is a subset of B containing only unique matrices.

Comment: You won't possibly be able to process 2^124 items. Even iterating through them won't be possible. Why do you think you need that?

Comment: tell us your base problem and we can advise you of a better way to perform the solution (hopefully), this is unfeasable.

Comment: Do you really need array? Maybe linked list would do the job. If you had sorted linked list you could have set of pointers pointing if the middle in case you need fast access to items inside. Like in the phonebook.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe the problem that makes you think the solution is that size array.

Comment: If you partitioned this counting task amongst a trillion parallel computers each running at a 1 picosecond clock speed, it would still take 2/3 of a million years to accomplish this task.

Comment: How many galaxies do you plan on demolishing in order to build enough RAM to store the array?

Comment: i just re-wrote the question guys

Comment: @Mike G: Is there an upper bound on the number of elements set B can have?

Comment: @Insilico yes all possible 10 by 10 matrices of binary entries

Comment: @Mike: So `B` might have 2^100 elements? Sorry to break the news, but you are vastly overestimating what computers are capable of. You *cannot* "scan through" 2^100 items.

Comment: 2^100 is about 10^30 - there are only (IIRC) 10^80 protons in the entire universe. You need to find a solution with slightly less storage requirements.

Comment: +1 after the rewrite, now it's understandable, though not solvable like you want it to be. ;)

Comment: Now you just need to edit it a *little* bit more - adding a question would probably be a good start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code, maybe not very efficient :

```
# include <vector>
# include <bitset>
# include <algorithm>

// I assume your 10x10 boolean matrix is implemented as a bitset of 100 bits.

// Comparison of bitsets
template<size_t N>
class bitset_comparator
{
    public :
      bool operator () (const std::bitset<N> & a, const std::bitset<N> & b) const
      {
          for(size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
          {
              if( !a[i] && b[i] )       return true ;
              else if( !b[i] && a[i] )  return false ;
          }
          return false ;
      }
} ;

int main(int, char * [])
{
    std::set< std::bitset<100>, bitset_comparator<100> > A ;
    std::vector< std::bitset<100> >                      B ; 


    // Fill B in some manner ...

    // Keeping unique elements in A
    std::copy(B.begin(), B.end(), std::inserter(A, A.begin())) ;
}
```

You can use `std::list`instead of `std::vector`. The relative order of elements in B is not preserved in A (elements in A are sorted).

*EDIT : I inverted A and B in my first post. It's correct now. Sorry for the inconvenience. I also corrected the comparison functor.*

Comment: I don't see why this is the accepted answer; I assumed "super long" meant "won't fit in memory". Everything becomes easier when it's a small problem.

Comment: The author edited his post and did not mention any memory constraint. I understood the question as "how to write a simple solution in C++" (as stated in the title).

Comment: Doesn't `std::set` require a less-than comparator? I don't think your `bitset_comparator` qualifies.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you might *really* be looking for a way to manage a large, sparse array. Trivially, you could use a hash map with your giant index as your key, and your data as the value. If you talk more about your problem, we might be able to find a more appropriate data structure for your problem.

*Update:*

If set B is just some set of matrices and not the set of all possible 10x10 binary matrices, then you just want a sparse array. Every time you find a new matrix, you compute its key (which could simply be the matrix converted into a 100 digit binary value, or even a 100 character string!), look up that index. If no such key exists, insert the value 1 for that key. If the key does exist, increment and re-store the new value for that key.

Comment: @Obscure, the hash output would have to be substantially less than 100 bits in length since otherwise you still need a 2^100-sized array which is what I think the OP posited to start with. But your idea is correct.

Comment: @paxdiablo you are correct, the 100-bit thing is the *key* not the hash. I'm going to move the corrected comment into my answer.

Comment: Don't use a sparse array but just a hash map with the 128bit number as the key (example). Or a `struct s{ uint64 lo, hi; };` with appropriate operator overloads to use it as a key.

Comment: @paxdiablo, any sane implementation of a hash container will further divide the hash into a fixed number of bins, and handle collisions of different hashes in the same bin. There's no need for a 2^100 array.

Comment: @Mark, that was from the original answer which seemed to indicate that the output of the hash function was 100 bits, which would then be used to index an array. Obscure has now clarified that so my comment is superfluous, but I can't remove it since then the whole comments section no longer makes sense :-) Actually, that gives me an idea for a feature request ...

Comment: sorry about the confusion - I could only delete my erroneous comment, not edit it. So I moved the text up to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Each element in the B is a 10 by 10 matrix where all entries are either 1 or 0.

Good, that means it can be represented by a 100-bit number. Let's round that up to 128 bits (sixteen bytes).

One approach is to use linked lists - create a structure like (in C):

```
typedef struct sNode {
    unsigned char bits[16];
    struct sNode *next;
};
```

and maintain the entire list `B` as a sorted linked list.

The performance will be somewhat less <sup>(a)</sup> than using the 100-bit number as an array index into a truly immense (to the point of impossible given the size of the known universe) array.

When it comes time to insert a new item into `B`, insert it at its desired position (before one that's equal or greater). If it was a brand new one (you'll know this if the one you're inserting before is different), also add it to `A`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Though probably not unmanageably so - there are options you can take to improve the speed.

One possibility is to use skip lists, for faster traversal during searches. These are another pointer that references not the next element but one 10 (or 100 or 1000) elements along. That way you can get close to the desired element reasonably quickly and just do the one-step search after that point.

Alternatively, since you're talking about bits, you can divide `B` into (for example) 1024 sub-`B` lists. Use the first 10 bits of the 100-bit value to figure out which sub-`B` you need to use and only store the next 90 bits. That alone would increase search speed by an average of 1000 (use more leading bits and more sub-`B`s if you need improvement on that).

You could also use a hash on the 100-bit value to generate a smaller key which you can use as an index into an array/list, but I don't think that will give you any real advantage over the method in the previous paragraph.

Comment: B is a large set arount 10,000,000 matrices. Searching a linked list everytime will be a nightmare, wouldnt it ?

Comment: @Mike, yes, hence the footnote. I'll add some more options.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each matrix into a string of 100 binary digits. Now run it through the Linux utilities:

```
sort | uniq
```

If you really need to do this in C++, it is possible to implement your own merge sort, then the `uniq` part becomes trivial.

Comment: @bitmask, thanks! I never knew about the `-u` option. That's one of the things I love about StackOverflow, learning new stuff when you least expect it. And now that you bring it up, the same feature could be added to a custom merge sort too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need N buckets where N is the number of all possible inputs. A [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) will just do fine. This is implemented with `set` class in C++.

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > > A; // vector of 10x10 matrices
// fill the matrices in A here

set<vector<vector<int> > > B(A.begin(), A.end()); // voila!
// now B contains all elements in A, but only once for duplicates
```